# Adding a new item to an array at Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have the following component structure in vue

Comment.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="site-comment" v-for="item in comments">
        <comment-item :comment="item" :comments="comments" :childs="childs"></comment-item>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And comment-item

```
  <div v-if="getChild(comment)">
      <comment :comments="childdsGett" :childs="childs"></comment>
    </div>
```

I am adding a new comment to the childdsGett array

```
axios.post('api/comment', {'parent_id': comment_id, 'text': this.comment_text}).then(function (data) {
             console.log(data.data)
             that.childdsGett.push(data.data)

          }).catch()
```

And got error

```
   You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
    
    found in
    
    ---> <CommentItem> at resources/js/components/CommentItem.vue
```

Comment: Where are calling that `axios.post` method?

Comment: After push button I call function

Answer (score 0):

My error was processing the response. An array is returned.

```
let data2 = data.data;

that.childdsGett.push(data2[0])
```